# Email Issue in AWS SES

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, amazon-ses

I have configured Email Id and Domains in SES Console and verified each of them. The region i selected is EU Ireland.

Using the SES Console i am able to send test mails to the verified ID.

I am however having issues in sending mail using lambda code.

Here is the piece of code driving me crazy:

```
var aws = require("aws-sdk");
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

aws.config.update({
  accessKeyId: "myaccesskey",
  secretAccessKey: "mysecretkey",
  region: "us-west-2"
});

var ses = new aws.SES();


exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {

    var mailOptions = {
        from: "myverifiedemailaddess@domain.com",
        subject: "This is an email sent from a Lambda function!",
        html: `<p>You got a contact message from: </b></p>`,
        to: "myverifiedemailaddess@domain.com",
        // bcc: Any BCC address you want here in an array,
    };

    // create Nodemailer SES transporter
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        SES: ses
    });

    // send email
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, info) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error sending email");
            callback(err);
        } else {
            console.log("Email sent successfully");
            callback();
        }
    });
};
```

Everytime i send and email using the code i get the below error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-WEST-2: myverifiedemailaddess@domain.com",
  "errorType": "MessageRejected",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Request.extractError (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/query.js:50:29)",
    "Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)",
    "Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)",
    "Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)",
    "Request.transition (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
    "AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
    "/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
    "Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)",
    "Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)",
    "Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Verify that email address from `SES>email addresses`, you cant sent email without verification of that email. Also region for EU Ireland is `eu-west-1`.

Comment: I have verified the address and they are shown as verfied. I also changed the region as eu-west-1 but then i got this error "  "errorMessage": "Inaccessible host: `email.us-west-1.amazonaws.com'. This service may not be available in the `us-west-1' region.",
  "errorType": "UnknownEndpoint","

Comment: are your lambda and `SES` in the same region ??

Comment: nopes- lamba is in Frankfurt and SES is in Ireland. Both need to be ?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/regions.html#region-receive-email , please read this, they needs to be in same region

Comment: Changed the Lambda function to the Ireland region and it started to work. Thnks Amol B Jamkar

Comment: that's great!!, I have added that comment as an answer please accept if it's ok.

Comment: You can have your Lambda function in a different region to SES. Just sure the correct region is chosen when you create the SES client. Your code above is showing Oregon (`us-west-2`) as the region for SES, which should be `eu-west-1` for Ireland.

Comment: Inaccessible host: email.us-west-1.amazonaws.com : seems like you have put us-west-1 in region instead of eu-west-1 :) SES is available in only 3 regions so far and they all are public endpoints and you should be able to reach them as long as you have internet access.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have `SES` and `Lambda` in the same region in order to work,

Please read this,

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/regions.html#region-receive-email

Comment: They only need to be in the same region for handling **incoming email**. For sending email, they do _not_ need to be in the same region.